# How to increase subtitle font size on MediaElement universal app

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, media-player, win-universal-app

I follow this [guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/VideoPlayback) to create a Video Player with subtitle. But by default, subtitle font size too small and I don't see any option to increase it. Anyone have idea?

[image: video playback]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the sample in detail, but I believe the Playercontrol is using Templates. Please try context menu on the control at design time. Check if there is something like edit templates or edit additional templates. When selecting those, a list should appear with several Templates you could edit. When you find something like "Subtititletemplate" or "MultiMediaTextblockStyle" this could be the one, your looking for. Select them and then you should be able to select the Textline and edit it with the property windows in Visual Studio.

HTH
Oliver

Comment: Thank but I don't see any options like that on MediaElement

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the font size programly. But you can/let user change the settings.
In system settings, search for "Closed Captions", then you can find the settings related.

[image]